# Issue with load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, apache-2.2

I am trying to load balance between two Apache http webservers. I created a load balancer using mod_proxy_balance from Apache.

When I run my client (which generates ~100s of threads every second and tries to browse through the website), after a few seconds I start getting 502 and 503 error response codes for few threads. There are few other threads that function properly.

I feel the loadbalancer might be overloaded but im not exactly sure. Can someone please let me know how to proceed in solving this issue? Thanks!

My proxy balancer setup:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_balancer.c>

    <Proxy balancer://hgcc13.org>
        BalancerMember http://hgccvm90.org/ loadfactor=1
        BalancerMember http://hgccvm92.org/ loadfactor=1
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass      balancer://hgcc13.org/
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

When I saw the error_log in the proxy , First I find

> " connection time out to the backend servers" 
>   , then i see
>
> " ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker" 
>   , and then
>
> " All workers are in error state",

The above 3 messages are repeated for a short amount of time. Then I find only

> "do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: Unable to send; errno = Operation not permitted ".

I ran the experiment only for 5 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect an issue with the backend servers, not the proxy itself.

The 502 errors are indicative of a lack of response from the balancer members.

The 503 errors indicate that one of the Apache services has hit its `MaxClients` setting - this *could* be the proxy, but if it is, then I suspect that's only because it's waiting on other requests to come back from the unresponsive backends.

Verify which system is hitting its limit by checking for "`server reached MaxClients`" in the Apache error log on each system.

You may need to adjust the timeout on the balancer members (the `ProxyTimeout` directive or the `timeout=x` setting on the `BalancerMember` lines), and/or the `MaxClients` (and related MPM settings) of the servers.

Comment: If I remove the proxy and let the client talk to one of the back server directly ... I didnt get any error then. If one server can handle the whole load, two servers should be able to handle it comfortably. Thats why i doubt the proxy.

Comment: When I saw the error_log in the proxy , First I find " connection time out to the backend servers" , then i see " ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker" , and then " All workers are in error state", After a mix of the above 3 messages are repeated for a short amount of time. Then I find only "do_ypcall: clnt_call: RPC: Unable to send; errno = Operation not permitted ". I ran the experiment only for 5 minutes.

Comment: Problem solved! I just disabled the firewall at the proxy !!